# Perform Static Analysis for a Domain Specific Language

Tags: compiler-construction, graph, dsl

I have a domain specific language and I want to do a static analysis on that language in order to great a graph. Appreciate if somebody could recommend a action plan on doing this.

**Domain Language**

```
{
   run_and_branch(ULSDCompHash)
   then
   {
      run(DownComponent_Reset);
      run(DownComponent_Reset2);

   }
   else
   {
      run(ULSD_EndOfTest);
   }
   run(ULSD_EndOfTest2);


}, closed,"EMCSETUP",""
```

**Details on the Language**

- run does not care if the condition pass or fail
- run_and_branch is like if - else, if pass or fail kind of thing
- The value within the () is the name of the node

**Expected Output (If Run a DFS on the Graph)**

```
 ULSDCompHash -> DownComponent_Reset -> DownComponent_Reset2 -> ULSD_EndOfTest2
 ULSDCompHash -> ULSD_EndOfTest -> ULSD_EndOfTest2
```

Comment: What kind of graph do you want to create exactly? A control flow graph? And is it an artifact of plain-text representation or should there really be separate nodes for things that occur in two code paths?

Comment: A control flow graph I feel is appropriate so that I can do DFS traversal to get all possible paths. The graph should mimic the plain text representation. So in my example there will be a single node ULSDCompHash that has a one out edge to DownComponent_Reset and another out edge to ULSD_EndofTest

Comment: After doing more googling around, the first step is to create the AST Tree for the source code and then transform that into Control Flow Graph. I am not able to find any good source like step by step explanation on how to transform the AST to CFG

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most compiler books contain pretty detailed descriptions of how to produce control flow graphs.

I provided an [SO answer as to how to crawl an AST to produce a CFG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989663/120163) for a Java program, but the answer is rather generic.