# How to retrieve a Control Flow Graph for python code?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree, control-flow-graph

I would like to dump the Control Flow Graph of a given python code,
similar to the option given by gcc compiler option: -fdump-tree-cfg for c code.

I succeeded getting the AST (Abstract Syntax Trees) of a python code,
but it seams quite complex and hassle to get the Control Flow Graph from AST phase.

Is there an easier way to retrieve directly the Control Flow Graph of a python code? any suggestions?

oh by the way I'm using python3.5

Thank you all!

P.S
I really don't know what kind of interpreter I'm using under the hood,
As far as I know it's CPython (not sure), I don't think it's PyPy(Rpython). 
Any suggestion how can I verify it?

Answer (score 5):

See my [SO answer on how to build a control flow graph, using an AST](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9989663/120163).

The original question asked about CFGs for Java, but the approach is actually pretty generic, and the same approach would work for producing a CFG for Python.

I wouldn't have called this "quite complex"; the basic idea is pretty simple.

Comment: ANTLR isn't the trick; it just builds an AST.   My answer tells you how to use the AST produced by any parser to produce a CFG.

Comment: Downvoter: Would you care to explain why this answer is not a good answer?

Comment: @JammingThebBits:  If you liked my answer, please upvote it (see upward pointing gray triangle at top of answer)

Comment: Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score

Comment: @JammingThebBits: Well, now you have score of 19 :-}